# Use ThreadPool for applicationwide logging?

Tags: multithreading, logging, threadpool

As a followup on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838447/threadpool-vs-dedicated-thread-when-to-prefer-which) discussing the use of the  ThreadPool vs a dedicated thread:

When would you use a dedicated thread (with lowered priority) for applicationwide logging and when would you use the ThreadPool?

Comment: Is there a correct answer to this question?

Comment: Modified question to make sure that there can be correct answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is completely dependent on the requirements of my app and its logging component.

If logging is mission-critical (maybe you need the ability to replay recent traffic based on the log, for example) then a dedicated thread is more likely the right approach.

If logging is 'best effort', then ThreadPool would be fine subject to other constraints on your app's required performance and latency.  Async I/O for the logger would be fine here. Since you suggest lower priority for your putative logger thread, this may match your app's profile.

If more critical work is happening on the ThreadPool then I would not overload it to do logging, esp. if logging itself is important - you could well be doing synchronous, flushed I/O to write out the logs and that's a possible bottleneck depending on the volume of stuff that you wish to log.

Comment: If it is 'best effort' how about this argument FOR a dedicated thread: You can alter (lower) the priority of a dedicated thread. AFAIK you can't (or shouln't) do that with the threadpool.

Comment: @bitbonk - I would not go to this trouble unless you must.  A better argument for dedicated thread might be to preserve ordering.  There are producer/consumer constructs built in to .Net to do that now, though.  Are you on .Net 4.0?

Comment: Not yet, but I might eventually.

Comment: @bitbonk - you might be able to use `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging` - this supports async logging in .Net 3.5 - see here for scenarios - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664736(v=PandP.50).aspx

Comment: Before adding a dependency on Entlib I'd rather add one for log4net. :) But so far I am confident that a small single class service would suffice for my needs.

Comment: I could not see where `log4net` supports async logging, but some off-the-shelf library is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If logging is not critical and you want to do it asynchronously then I would recommend using a single background thread for logging and a producer/consumer queue to send log messages.  This can achieve improved performance over threadpool since you have a single thread performing I/O on less-critical logs which would have less of a likelyhood to block higher-priority I/O on other threads.

You can also use this mechanism to make sure critical logs are committed before logging.  Add them to the queue and then have a mechanism to wait until that particular message is committed.