# What is Dedicated thread ? please explain

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, threadpool

I would like to know what exactly the dedicated thread means?

Is there any difference between a normal thread and a dedicated thread?

Comment: Can you please cite with a bit more context? Where did you find this term? Probably it just means an explicitely created thread in contrast to a thread pool thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ThreadPool vs dedicated Thread - when to prefer which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838447/threadpool-vs-dedicated-thread-when-to-prefer-which) (i really recommend more exercise in using _search engines_)

Comment: A dedicated thread is just a thread created for a single purpose. It's not re-used for multiple purposes, i.e. it's dedicated for one purpose.

Comment: It would probably help if you described or linked to the source where that term was used.

Comment: "Dedicated thread" is a not an official term or super-important property of thread. It's just a meaning. The thread will be performing a dedicated job and nothing else. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices#:~:text=that%20benefits%20from%20a-,dedicated%20thread,-.%20On%20a%20single) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/threads-and-threading#:~:text=can%20also%20use%20a-,dedicated%20thread,-for%20network%20or) are some usage examples.

Answer (score 1):

A thread dedicated to one job and one job only, so for the life time of the application the thread number 1 will only do one thing.

A non-dedicated thread is a thread that when it finishes the job the thread will be freed to be re-used for a different job.